# Magento - add a custom left that appear with the products only

Tags: magento

I need to add a custom left to appear on the products pages only.

I hope if you can help

Answer (score 0):

if you want them to appear on the listing page then you have to add your block here :

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
   ......Add your block here ..............
        </reference>
```

but if you want it to appear on detail page too then

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="left">
       ......Add your block here ..............
            </reference>
```

You can find both these above in catalog.xml but just in case you use other than default them then you have to do it in local.xml.

Don't forget to vote up or click the answer (tick) on left If this helps you.